# Footer position

Tags: html, css

I have a footer which i always want to be at the bottom like this:

[image]

It must be at the bottom at all time.. I thought the correct way to do this was with css:

```
#generated_footer_date {
color:#ffffff;
width:100%;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
text-align:center;
padding-top:15px;
height:50px;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
position:absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin-top:100px;
}
```

But now when i click on generate it displays data on the page which makes the page longer and [image]

When i click on generate the page becomes longer but the footer stays in its own place and looks like that. I thought i could solve this issue with jquery. If i click the button i could change the position of the footer from absolute to relative and then it would work, but can i do this with css?

Comment: Use Javascript for it. Onclick event match height with window's height and set position according to it.

Comment: can you post more of your html?

Comment: aha i didnt think html was needed in this case @Dejan.S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try:

```
footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing from `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;`

```
#generated_footer_date {
    color:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:15px;
    height:50px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```